# HTML to CSS (from inspect element)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, inspect

I am trying to find the CSS code to place in my wordpress backend to float my page element in the center. I have figured out how to float center, but not how to convert the HTML into CSS. 
please help 
[image]

Comment: is this on your local?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: margin: 0 auto; use this one ?

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you're looking for is:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0 auto; is correct

However, remember that margin auto won't work on a floated element

See here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpLZVR

```
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.breaks-if-floated {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  max-width: 800px;
  float: left;
}
```